# What is Jehovah's Witnesses view of Revelation 20:10 since they do not believe in hell?

Tags: exegesis, satan, jehovahs-witnesses, hell, revelation

I know that Jehovah's Witnesses do not believe in hellfire but in that case, how do they interpret scriptures such as [Revelation 20:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020%3A10&version=KJV), which says

> And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and
>   brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be
>   tormented day and night for ever and ever. (KJV)

According to Jehovah's Witnesses, what is this verse a description of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find out what the "lake of fire" is, continue reading down to [verses 13 and 14 (KJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020%3A13-14&version=KJV):

> 13 And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and death and hell delivered up the dead which were in them: and they were judged every man according to their works.
>
> 14 And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.

These verses explain what Jehovah's Witnesses believe. The "lake of fire" means "the second death," which is the condition of eternal destruction. ([2 Thessalonians 1:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Thessalonians%201%3A9&version=KJV)) As you may notice, it's not the same as hell, because hell is thrown *into* the lake of fire. Death and hell are destroyed forever.

For more information, see:

- [What Is Hell? Is It a Place of Eternal Torment?](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/what-is-hell/)
- [What Is the Lake of Fire? Is It the Same as Hell or Gehenna?](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/lake-of-fire/)

Answer (score 0):

As I am studying this myself I have a follow up question. Yes, hell and deathbare destroyed forever in the Lake of Fire. It is not stated that hell is where eternal torment happens, but rather in the lake of fire. While Hell and death are sent there, along with Satan and the false prophet, also everyone not written in the book of life are also thrownninto the lake of fire wherein verse 10 is where eternal torment happens. So hell aside, as that is translated from Sheol/Hades which really translates to the grave, what are JW view specifically of the lake of fire?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/75890)

Comment: The JW view of the "lake of fire" is given in the answer by user32540: the lake of fire symbolizes the second death, a term for eternal destruction. The second death is in contrast to the death that exists due to Adam's sin ([Romans 5:12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/45/5#s=12&study=parallel&v=45:5:12)) and from which resurrection is possible. So when the verse says that death is thrown in the lake of fire, it means that the death from Adam ceases to exist for all eternity.

Comment: The JW view ([see here](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1101988040?#h=41-42)) of the torment in verse 10 relates to the original Greek word βασανισθήσονται (basanisthēsontai), used in verse 10 in the form "they will be tormented". This word is related to the Greek word basanos which, as explained by [Strong's Greek Concordance](https://biblehub.com/greek/931.htm), refers to a "touchstone" (a dark stone used in ancient times to test if an item was real gold). So the verse 10 is saying that the end of Satan, "the beast", and "the false prophet" becomes a reference case for all eternity.

Comment: I know this response is late, however, I did research your answer and there is still one pressing question I have. If JW believe that Revelation 20:10 states the devil and the false prophet are to serve as a touchstone as that is another translation of the original Greek, then why does the NWT of the bible not translate it that way, but rather, stated in itself they will be tormented? If the NWT is the holy accurate word of God then you shouldn't have to re-translate portions in order to come to the truth. If this is the case, please also explain how the NWT can be trusted.